# How insert rows into table with two primary key?

Tags: sql-server

I have created following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblArchLogDetail](
    [RecordID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [TableName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [TotalRecords] [int] NULL,
    [ArchivedRecords] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblArchLogDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RecordID] ASC,
    [TableName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So, how can I insert rows into this table? I keeps getting error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint".
This is my sample code:

```
Insert into tblArchLogDetail values(54,'tblAuditLogin',13128,0)
```

Comment: Why are you quoting numeric values? `RecordID`, `TotalRecords`, and `ArchivedRecords` are all numbers; remove the quotes from around the values. `INSERT INTO tblArchLogDetail VALUES (54, 'tblAuditLogin', 13128, 0)` should be correct for the schema you've shown. I don't think it solves the issue you're having, but it's not proper SQL.

Comment: Yup, it's not solving my issue. I also get error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblArchLogDetail'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblArchLogDetail'". What I'm planning to do is inserting a group of rows into the table.

Comment: Then you have your answer: Don't insert duplicate keys. :-) If you have a primary key (no matter how many columns), the primary key has to be distinct. You have more than one row that has the same values for your two primary key columns, and you even specify `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement - that means "don't ignore duplicate keys", meaning "don't allow them to happen".

Comment: this is cluster primary key (RecordID,TableName). For instance, 
54 tblAudtTrail 429559 1
54 tblCardType 4 4
55 tblAudtTrail 429559 1
55 tblCardType 4 4

Comment: Yup, something wrong with syntax?

Comment: looks like sqlserver, at least I've never built tables with columns between `[]`

Comment: Query this: `Select * from tblArchLogDetail where RecordID = 54 and TableName = 'tblAuditLogin'` If the query has results...that is why you receive the `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint` error.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a so called "composite" primary key.

This means that any **combination** of values you chose to make up your composite primary key must be unique.

The error you are getting only means that you already have a record in that table whose RecordId is 54 and TableName is 'tblAuditLogin'.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're trying to do is add an automatically incrementing integer in `RecordID` field.  If so, make it an identity field:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblArchLogDetail](
    [RecordID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [TableName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [TotalRecords] [int] NULL,
    [ArchivedRecords] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblArchLogDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RecordID] ASC,
    [TableName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If that's not your intent and you really want duplicate records in `RecordID` and `TableName`, put an identity field before RecordID and add it to the PRIMARY KEY constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblArchLogDetail](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY NOT NULL
    [RecordID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [TableName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [TotalRecords] [int] NULL,
    [ArchivedRecords] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblArchLogDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [RecordID] ASC,
    [TableName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If those two solutions don't fix it, you have additional details that are required to answer this question.